# How do I have a web page store changes made by javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a form on a simple web page that has a series of checkboxes.  These options represent items that may be retrieved from a database upon clicking the submit button.  In addition, there is a place to add an extra option to the page at the bottom.  Here is what I am going for:

I would like to be able to add the new option using javascript, so that it show up quickly and seamlessly to the user, rather than having to send the request back to the server and add it server-side, then have the user reload the page.  However, I also want to make sure that these added fields are preserved so that the next time I load the page, they show up.

Unfortunately, my code is proprietary, so I cannot post it here.  I hope that people can help me this some ideas without having to actually see the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When these checkboxes are added you don't want to go the server but when user presses submit you are anyways going to server, so at that time you can persist this information about new checkboxes on server.

Another option is to call to server asynchronously using AJAX to update the server about the state change.

Comment: This works for the common case, but there is a small nuance regarding a user adding a checkbox but leaving it unselected.  the new checkbox does not show up in the `$_POST` data.

Comment: In that case you can keep a hidden field corresponding to each checkbox.

Comment: Eureka! Hidden fields.  Thanks! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to store the changes server-side, you can do so quietly in the background.

Just use [`XmlHttpRequest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest), together with a PHP script.

Comment: Is this supported by all browsers, or will I have to write separate scripts for each browser?

Comment: Works on Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera and IE since version 7. For older IE versions, you can use `ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")` or `ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` instead (with try/catch, for example). Only the first line changes. The rest of the code is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HTML5 local storage API](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/) to store your changes.

```
localStorage.setItem('favoriteflavor','vanilla');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want session related information to pass thru multiple requests, you can either put the data in a cookie, or with php you can use sessions.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php